# can I run tests for a web application running on EC2 instance from an AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a web application running on EC2 instance. Planning to write some integration tests and one of the option I am thinking is to deploy the test suite as a lambda and run them pointing to the web app on the EC2 instance. My understanding is the Lambda can be associated with an EFS volume so that the test results are written to it.

I have not worked on lambda earlier and could not find an instance/example on the web stating the usage of lambda in this way (test suite). I want to know if the above option is technically feasible. If it is possible, will there be any challenges?
Please advise.

Comment: An AWS Lambda function can run for a maximum of 15 minutes, so it might not be ideal depending on how many tests you need to run. Your other option is to launch a small EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

running your test suite in AWS Lambda is definitely doable and there are projects like https://github.com/lambci/lambci and https://github.com/lambci/serverless-actions that use AWS Lambda as runners for CI/CD. As for saving the results of the tests, you might want to consider saving to S3 instead of EFS to make the solution simpler.